# itextsharp PdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField giving error

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have a PDF containing Chinese, Japanese language. In that PDF I have some input fields. I want to fill this PDF dynamically in C#.net

I am using iTextSharp dll to read pad and successfully read the PDF fields but when I am going to set value with `PdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField`, it gives me this error

> Font 'KozMinPro-Regular' with 'UniJIS-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

To read PDF and getting fields I am using the following code

```
string pdfTemplate = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.pdf";
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
{
   sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

And I am getting all fields successfully.

To fill data in PDF I am using this code

```
string pdfTemplate = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.pdf";
string newFile = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\newdata_test.pdf";

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
            newFile, FileMode.Create));

AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;         

// set form pdfFormFields
pdfFormFields.SetField("fill_17", "test");
```

I am facing error on `pdfFormFields.SetField` method as

> Font 'KozMinPro-Regular' with 'UniJIS-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

Please advice what I have to change or how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are some files missing in your project. In order to use the font 'KozMinPro-Regular' with 'UniJIS-UCS2-H', you need to give iTextSharp access to the metrics files that contain information about that font. These metrics files can be downloaded separately from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/extras/). More specifically, you need the file iTextAsian-dll-2.1.zip that can be found in iTextAsian-all-2.1.zip

Note that this will only work with a recent version of iTextSharp (5.3.0.0 or higher). This iTextAsian DLL won't work with older versions of iTextSharp.

Comment: I have generated pdf successfully with above, but text showing in fields are much larger by default and when I am clicking on it text goes again smaller. May be because fields having auto font size property. Please help me into this

Comment: A font size is defined at the level of the field. If this size is 0, then iText will pick a font size. If it isn't 0, then iText will use the font size that is defined.

Comment: Yes, but if we defined font size then our text will not fit into field in case of long size text. So I have set font size to 0 and its working fine. But in my case pdf showing larger font at the time of PDF open and when we click on text box then it become smaller.

Comment: Well... that's something you have to live with if you set the font size to 0. There's no rule that defines which exact font size should be used for the default appearances if you use 0. An alternative would be to tell iText no to generate appearances. In that case, the appearances will be created by the PDF viewer.